# why snap requests capable of net_admin, perfmon etc?

Tags: snap

I have tons of audit message like:

```
 AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/core/nnnnn/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=mmm comm="snap-confine" capability=kk  capname="net_admin"
```

Is snapd create some kind of security risk?